# Github number of additions/deletions don't seem to add up to the number of line of a project

Tags: javascript, git, github

I am trying to build a tool that shows the progression of the number of line a git project
To calculate this value, I use the number of additions and deletions by week provided by the Github API ([Route used here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-all-contributor-commit-activity)).
The idea is to add for each week the number of additions and subtract the number of deletions to get the number of line in the project each week.

I tried doing that and got this graph from the linux repository.

[image: Graph from github data]

As you can see the number of line drop below 0, so there must be a problem somewhere.

The Github api call gives an array of contribution.

```
type contribution = {
  author: any
  total: number //Number of commits
  weeks: contrbution_of_the_week[]
}

type contrbution_of_the_week = {
  w: number //week id
  a: number //additions of the week
  d: number //deletion of the week
  c: number //commits of the week
}
```

Here is the code. y_arr and x_arr represent the y and x axis.

```
const data: contribution[] = response.data
//Get the number of week
const number_of_week = data[0].weeks.length
let number_of_line = 0

//For each week
for (let i = 0; i < number_of_week; i++) {

  let current_week = data[0].weeks[i].w
  x_arr.push(current_week)

  //For each contributor
  for (let contribution of data) {

    let week_contribution = contribution.weeks[i]

    if (week_contribution) {
      number_of_line += (week_contribution.a - week_contribution.d)
    } else {
      console.log("Week not found")
    }

  }

  y_arr.push(number_of_line)

}
```

When running the code, there is no occurrence of "Week not found" (Every contributors has the same number of week_contribution) and after examination the weeks array is ordered (weeks[0] represents the contribution_of_the_week of the first week of the project for every contributor).

The problem might come from a misunderstanding of the git additions and deletions as I can't find their definition in the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs). But when testing out, additions and deletions seems to match the number of line deleted and added for single commits.

Thank you and have a great day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update: Since 8th january 2024 Github changed it APIs:

> Beginning January 8th, 2024, we will be making changes to the repository insights UI and API on GitHub for repositories with over 10,000 commits. The targeted UI and API have very low usage and rely on a legacy service we’re moving away from.

> The REST API responses for repositories with 10,000+ commits will report 0 values for the addition and deletion counts to improve performance. This impacts the /repos/{owner}/{repo}/stats/contributors endpoint to [get all contributor commit activity](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/metrics/statistics?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-all-contributor-commit-activity)
>
> The /repos/{owner}/{repo}/stats/code_frequency [API endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/metrics/statistics?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-the-weekly-commit-activity) will return a 422 status code for repos with 10,000 or more commits.
> This is different from the previous two because this endpoint only returns additions/deletions, which we will no longer return for repos with over 10k commits. The previous two endpoints also return the total number of commits, which we will continue to generate.

This way, they are suggesting the following command (I've added `>> stats.txt` to output in a file but you can remove it):

```bash
git log --pretty="format:%m%ad----%ae%n%-(trailers:only,unfold)" --date=raw --shortstat --no-renames --no-merges >> stats.txt
```

You'll need to write your own script to count the amount of additions and deletions in repositories with more than 10k commits.
To achieve this, you can store the output in a file and ran a script like this one written in NodeJS in the same directory as the file:

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('stats.txt'); // The name of your file

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
});

const emailStats = {};

var currentEmail = null;
var currentInsertions = 0;
var currentDeletions = 0;

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    if (line.startsWith('>')) {
        const emailMatch = line.match(/----(\S+@\S+)/);
        if (emailMatch) 
            currentEmail = emailMatch[1];
    } else if (line.includes('insertion') || line.includes('deletion')) {
        const counts = line.match(/(\d+) insertion[s]?[^\d]*(\d+) deletion[s]?/);
        if (counts) {
            currentInsertions += parseInt(counts[1], 10);
            currentDeletions += parseInt(counts[2], 10);

            if (currentEmail in emailStats) {
                emailStats[currentEmail].insertions += currentInsertions;
                emailStats[currentEmail].deletions += currentDeletions;
                emailStats[currentEmail].commits += 1;
            } else {
                emailStats[currentEmail] = {
                    insertions: currentInsertions,
                    deletions: currentDeletions,
                    commits: 1,
                };
            }

            currentInsertions = 0;
            currentDeletions = 0;
        }
    }
});

rl.on('close', () => {
    console.log(emailStats);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the doc is not very explicit on this : only the top 100 contributors are returned by this route.

---

The combined contributions of *all commits* should indeed match the lines present in a repo.

When you look at the contribution user by user, or of only a subset of users, however, there is no such guarantee.

Comment: But for each week, I add the contributions of all contributors. (for (let contribution of data)) don't I?

Comment: How many elements are there in `data` ? are all the authors mentioned ?

Comment: The Github route is called "Get all contributor commit activity", so I thought that was the case but there are only 100 contributors. I guess the GitHub api route only send the activity of 100 contributors as the Linux project probably has far more.

Comment: Could you update your answer so that I can accept it ?